# Excel VBA Open Macro

Tags: excel, vba

The Excel VBA code below executes when I open my Excel document on my computer. However, when someone else opens my document, the code does not execute (VBA macros are enabled). I am also having the same issue with the custom ribbon I designed for the Excel document. When I open my Excel document on my computer the custom ribbon appears. However, when someone else opens my document, the custom ribbon does not appear.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .DisplayFormulaBar = False
        .Width = 845
        .Height = 408
    End With
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayRuler = False
        .DisplayHeadings = False
    End With
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Could someone please explain to me how I could fix this ongoing issue. I don't understand why the Excel workbook formating is different between my computer and my colleagues computer.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you transfer the file to the other computer? Was it through email? Does the other person work for the same company and have the same trust settings as you do?

Comment: If you customised your ribbon using File.Advanced.Customize Ribbon then this is only customisation for the current installation.  It will not appear on other machines.

Comment: Another possibility why your open event code might fail is if user's Excel events are disabled, which you can check in the Immediate window with ?Application.EnableEvents. If you don't have access to check, move all your code to a normal module and change Sub Workbook_Open > Sub Auto_Open()

Comment: @freeflow Yes, I did do the ribbon with File.Advanced.Customize. Would there be a way that I could write code for the ribbon in VBA? Thanks for responding fast.

Comment: @braX The file was shared through SharePoint. Yes, the other person does work in the same company (Same Settings). Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: VBA to modify the ribbon is relatively straightforward.   There are many examples if you google for them.